# Visual studio 2013 express crashes when trying to debug C++ dll (x64) using excel

Tags: c++, excel, dll, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

I am a beginner, and I just built a project including a dll in c++. The project is made up with 2 sub projects:

1. A static Library project containing the files:

Rational.h

```
#pragma once

class Rational
{
private:
    int num;
    int den;

public:
    Rational(int num_, int den_);
    Rational();

    double getValue();

};
```

Rational.cpp

```
#include "Rational.h"

Rational::Rational()
{
}

Rational::Rational(int num_, int den_) : den(den_), num(num_)
{
}

double Rational::getValue()
{
    return  (double)num / (double) den;
}
```

2. A dll project containing the files:

Proxy.h

```
#pragma once

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C"
{
    DLL_EXPORT double __stdcall getRationalValue(int num_, int den_);
}
```

Proxy.cpp

```
#include "Proxy.h"
#include "Rational.h"


DLL_EXPORT double __stdcall getRationalValue(int num_, int den_)
{
    Rational fraction(num_, den_);

    return fraction.getValue();
}
```

The dll function is used in an Excel file. Here is the declaration of the function to be used:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function getRationalValue_vba Lib "C:\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Rational\x64\Debug\RationalDll.dll" Alias "getRationalValue" (ByVal num As Long, ByVal den As Long) As Double
```

In order to test this function I have the following sub in vba:

```
Sub test()

    shtTests.Cells(1, 1) = getRationalValue_vba(4, 5)

End Sub
```

It seems to work fine.

The problem occurs when I want to launch the debugger from Visual Studio.
In visual studio project:

Properties>Debugging>Command was set to Excel.exe localisation.

I set a break point at the "return" line of proxy.cpp file. 
When I launch the debugger, excel opens well. But then, when I execute sub test(), the break point in visual is never reached, and the application crashes.

Can you help me understand this issue?

Comment: A VBA `Long` is 64-bits.  Is `sizeof(int) == 8`?  If not, then that is the probable reason for the crash -- you are mixing different size parameter types.

Comment: Try using `#include <cstdint>` and `int64_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: Thanks for answering PaulMcKenzie. I tried it (in Proxy.h and Proxy.cpp files). unfortunately it still crashes.

Comment: You need to determine the reason for the crash and where the crash is occurring.   The call stack shows you what the problem could be, as well as the message you get as to the reason for the crash.

Comment: I would really like to. But as I told you I don't have good knowledge in programming. Is there a link you can give me where I could learn how to see the "Call stack" please? I don't get any message, just a crash.

Comment: When you run the program in the debugger, the call stack window shows the function calls that led up to the crash.  You should also confirm that the VBA function is actually calling your DLL function, and the crash is not due to some other issue.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand better. The problem is that visual studio just crashes. So after the function call in VBA, it is not possible anymore to access visual studio and read the call stack. I guess everything is ok on vba side because it works well when not ran in debug mode.